# Select sqlite3 row by second column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm using a small python program to query an sqlite3 database of ingredients and recipes.

I want to find out how much of a certain ingredient I have by searching it by name.

I'm currently using:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT amount FROM Ingredients WHERE ingredient_name = Pasta')
```

When I run the program I get `'no such column: Pasta'`. It works when I search by the id instead. How can I solve this?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld54C.png)

Comment: You need single quotes around string constants.  I view this as a typo error and vote to close.

Comment: Better would be to use: `cursor.execute('SELECT amount FROM Ingredients WHERE ingredient_name = ?', ('Pasta',))`

Comment: If `ingredient_name` is a string column, you need double quotes around the question mark, like so: `cursor.execute('SELECT amount FROM Ingredients WHERE ingredient_name = "?"', ('Pasta',))`

Comment: @JordanSinger no you don't. For parameterized queries, you just use the `?` placeholder, no double quotes. If you are hard-coding the parameter value, then the string itself needs to be quoted (which is the issue the OP has)

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, fair enough.

Comment: @JordanSinger in fact, with quotation marks around `?`, it is no longer recognised as a binding parameter. Your code will throw an error. Just did a quick test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way of executing a query is as follows:

```
cursor.execute(QUERY, params)
```

So you can do the following:

```
QUERY = "SELECT amount FROM Ingredients WHERE ingredient_name = ?"
cursor.execute(QUERY, ('Pasta',))
```